# How to increase timeout when win_nssm (nssm via Ansible) starts a service?

Tags: ansible, timeout, nssm

Starting my Windows nssm Service via the Ansible plugin win_nssm sometimes fails because the service status is `SERVICE_START_PENDING` while the defined state should be `started`.

This seems to happen because the system is under heavy load and the service needs more time than expected to start - which is not a problem. But I do not find a configuration property where I can set the startup timeout to something like 5min or so.

Answer (score 0):

Use `win_service` to start your nssm service instead.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/55129) "state" option will be deprecated in favor of "win_service".

> Starting from Ansible 2.8, the started value for the state option will be deprecated, in favor of using the win_service module (see #45693).